# How do I use CTE for this

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Sample table Structure,

```
 Create table #table(advId int identity(1,1),name nvarchar(100),ranks nvarchar(5),ReferId int ,ReferalRank nvarchar(5))

 insert into #table(name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('King','MGR',0,'0')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Maceij','MGR',1,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Los','MGR',1,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Los1','ADV',1,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Griff','MGR',1,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('SA','MGR',2,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('CASSANDRA','MGR',2,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Jason','MGR',3,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Smith','MGR',3,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Akee','MGR',6,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Manasa','ADV',6,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Akee','MGR',10,'MGR')
 insert into #table (name,ranks,ReferId,ReferalRank) values('Manasa','ADV',10,'MGR')

 select *from #table
```

Let me have words about my Table Structure
 Here ,
 AdvId 1 is Referred by admin ,
  (2,3,4,5) are 1st level of 1
 (6,7,8,9) are 2nd Level of 1
 (10,11) are 3rd level of 1
 (12,13) are 4 th Level of 1
 same Logic  For Each Advisors
[Like This Structure](http://behindmlm.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/5x5-matrix-mlm-compensation-plan.jpg)

How do I Select the Count Of Manager(how many manager under the agent) for Each Advisors up to 3 Levels

```
 advId name     CountOfmanager
 1     king       8            --2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10
 2     Maceij     3            --6,7,10
 3      los       2            --8,9
 4     Los1       0            -- nobody 
 5     Griff      0        -- nobody 
 6     SA         2            -- 10,12   
 7     CASSANDRA  0            -- nobody 
 8     Jason      0
 9     Smith      0
10    Akee       1             --12
11    manasa     0
12    Akee       0
13    Manasa     0
```

This is what I Tried.

```
with cte (advId,ReferId,Level)
as
(
 select AdvId,ReferId,1 as Level from table where ReferId=1
 union all
 select a.AdvId,a.ReferId ,Level+1 from table   
 as a inner join cte as b on b.AdvId=a.ReferId
 )
 select COUNT(b.AdvId) From cte as a inner join table 
 as b on a.advId=b.advId where a.level<=3 and b.ranks='MGR'
```

I hope its Clear ,Assist me to get the Result

Comment: Question from your expected answer, why 11 is not part of 2? 11 has Refid 6 which has RefId 2. Similarly 12 and 13 should also be included in the count for 6, becuase they have ReferId 10 which has ReferId 6.

Comment: Actually I need to select Who are 'MGR' rank,11 and 13 are 'ADV' thats why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My result a bit different from yours in first 2 rows, because for king and Maceij you missing 12 (Akee), if you have 12 for 10, you also must have it for 1 and 2 advIDs.

First I find deep level of every row.

Second I put parents to each of rows.

Third count childs

And for the last I just show result.

```
;WITH alignRef AS (

        SELECT advId, name, ranks, ReferId, ReferalRank, 0 AS DeepLevel 
        FROM #table
        WHERE ReferId = 0

        UNION ALL

        SELECT T.advId, T.name, T.ranks, T.ReferId, T.ReferalRank, R.DeepLevel+1 AS DeepLevel 
        FROM #table T
        INNER JOIN alignRef AS R
            ON T.ReferId = R.advId
            --AND T.ranks = R.ranks

     ), getParents AS ( 
         SELECT advId, name, ranks, ReferId, ReferalRank, DeepLevel, advId AS ParentID
         FROM alignRef
         WHERE ranks='MGR' AND DeepLevel <= 4

         UNION ALL

         SELECT R.advId, R.name, R.ranks, R.ReferId, R.ReferalRank, R.DeepLevel, CC.ParentID AS ParentID 
         FROM getParents AS CC
         INNER JOIN alignRef AS R
            ON CC.advId = R.ReferId
        WHERE R.ranks='MGR' AND R.DeepLevel <= 4

    ), CountChilds AS (
        SELECT ParentID, COUNT(*) AS Amount
        FROM getParents
        WHERE advId <> ParentID
        GROUP BY ParentID
    )
    SELECT T.advId, T.name, ISNULL(CC.Amount, 0) AS CountOfmanager
    FROM #table AS T
    LEFT JOIN CountChilds AS CC
        ON CC.ParentID = T.advId
    ORDER BY T.advId
```

Result:

```
advId   name        CountOfmanager
1       King        9
2       Maceij      4
3       Los         2
4       Los1        0
5       Griff       0
6       SA          2
7       CASSANDRA   0
8       Jason       0
9       Smith       0
10      Akee        1
11      Manasa      0
12      Akee        0
13      Manasa      0
```

Comment: Thank you So much. its awesome bit tough to understand .Thank you Again

Comment: Result is differ because OP wants to get data up to 4 level and your CTE query provides data including 4 level. Up-voted!

Comment: I changes it "WHERE ranks='MGR' AND DeepLevel < 4" :).